# Check all checkboxes by default

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So I have this checkbox group

```
 b-form-checkbox-group.ml-4.b-check(
              v-model="selected",
              v-if="productGroup.show",
              :options="productGroup.products",
```

I am trying to have the list of :options to be checked by default. I am having issues with settign this up.

Here is my code, I don't know why it is not working.

```js
 toggleAll(checked, productGroup) {
      if (checked) {
        let productIds = this.selected ? [...this.selected] : [];
        productGroup.products.forEach((product) => {
          productIds.push(product.id);
        });
        this.selected = _.uniq(productIds);
      } else {
        let temp = [...this.selected];
        productGroup.products.forEach((product) => {
          if (temp.indexOf(product.id) > -1) {
            temp.splice(temp.indexOf(product.id), 1);
          }
        });
        this.selected = temp;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your option group is an array of object data, and you will use another array to track the selected options, as follows:

```js
data() {
  return {
    selected1: [],
    group1: [
      { id: 1, text: 'Item 1', value: 'item1' },
      { id: 2, text: 'Item 2', value: 'item2' }
    ]
  }
}
```

Your `toggleAll` method needs to add all the group's values to the tracking array to toggle them on, and it needs to remove all values to toggle them off:

```js
methods: {
  toggleAll(checked, group, selected) {
    // First remove any selected items, regardless of the toggle state
    selected.splice(0, selected.length)
    // Now, if the toggle is true, add all items
    if (checked) {
      group.forEach(o => selected.push(o.value));
    }
  }
}
```

Using the example data above, call the above method like:

```js
this.toggleAll(true, this.group1, this.selected1);
```